# Convert Integer into Bytestring - Python

Tags: python, integer, byte

I want to convert an integer, for example 2900 into the bytestring b'\x0b\x54'. When I try

```
variable = 2900
print(hex(variable))
print(variable.to_bytes(2, 'little'))
```

I receive the following:

```
0xb54
b'T\x0b'
```

Comment: Seems like you want `'big'` instead of `'little'`

Comment: That's the same as  `b'\x0b\x54'`

Comment: Because `0x54` is the ascii code for `T`, and bytestrings show elements as characters when it's simple to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v = 2900
v.to_bytes(2, 'big')
```

gives

```
b'\x0bT'
```

which is the same as

```
b'\x0b\x54'
```

`0x54` is the ascii code for `T`, so character `'\x54'` is the same as the character `'T'`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module for this:

```
import struct
struct.pack('<h', 2900)
```

will return `b'T\x0b'`
or :

```
struct.pack('>h', 2900)
```

to get `b'\x0bT'`